# C APIs: why are functions using returnParameters with buffer + size instead of returning char*

Tags: c, memory-management, parameters, return

I am not using C all that much, but when I do I notice that many APIs are using return parameters with a buffer and it's max size instead of returning a pointer to the requested buffer. Why is that, and more importantly - do I have to do that for every function I use only privately?

take:

```
int crazy_c_getSomeText(char* buf, int len);
```

while this:

```
char* crazy_c_getSomeText();
```

is much less verbose and does the same, doesn't it?

Well you don't have the returned `int` of the first function which might be an error code. Is that the only reason or am I overseeing some memory management related things?

**Update:** Thanks for the quick replies! I see that there is more that I didn't consider: accessibility and uncertainty about allocation. But what if the functions are not some library functions but some local helpers? Then I can be sure the memory is accessible and I know how the memory is held.

Comment: The former does not do what you say it does. Those are not "return parameters". They are passed into the function and are not modified as far as the caller is concerned (function parameters are always *passed by value* in C). That is, your comparison is invalid as the former is not returning buffer+size.

Comment: Because then the caller have full control over the buffer, instead of relying on the function to allocate memory. Or worse, having the called function use a static buffer and returning a pointer to it. And what if the buffer is not actually a string? How would the caller then find out the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; I think you are overseeing some memory management related things.

On top of my mind--and given my experience using .NET P/Invoke--I could say that, if I were to try to use a C API like the latter's signature in C#, I would most likely crash my application i.e., the "string" will be created in a location of memory my .NET Application may not have access to; any attempt to access the return value will cause problems. I think this is the case in many scenarios.

I believe it is not a good practice to assume the client of an API has access to the same portion of memory as the API itself.

Furthermore, in environments without automatic memory reclaiming (as is the case in C), every entity should "clean" after itself. `char* crazy_c_lib_getSomeText();` would not have such an option.